Is there any Banach space other than $\ell^p$ satisfies these conditions?
Let $X$ be a Banach space.
There exists a biorthogonal system $(x_i, f_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}},$ where $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ and $(f_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X^*$ such that for some $p>1$ the conditions:
(i) $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty |f(x_i)|^p < \infty \ \text{for all} \  f \in X^*$;
(ii) $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty |f_i(x)|^q < \infty \ \text{for all} \  x \in X$;
(iii) $\{f_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is $w^*$-linearly dense in $X^*,$
are satisfied, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1.$
My question is there any Banach space other than $l^p$ satisfies the previous conditions together.
Is there any Banach space can satisfy any of these conditions?
Can Theorem of Morell and Retherford help in anything
Theorem of Morell and Retherford
If $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space and $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of real numbers convergent to zero with $0 < a_i < 1,$ then there is a basic sequence $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ such that $\|x_i\| = a_i$ for all $i$ and $$\displaystyle \sup \Big \{\left (\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x^*(x_i)|^2 \right )^{1/2} : x^* \in X^*, \|x^*\| \leq 1  \Big \} \leq 1.$$

The map $X\to\ell^q, x\mapsto (f_i(x))_i$ is bounded and injective. If $X$ is reflexive, it is also surjective, but I am not sure how to get that $X$ is reflexive
